# How to get all learners in the database with a specific Grade and subject?

Tags: laravel

I have this blade file witch brings the Authenticated User (Teacher), Grade and subjects he is teaching. what I want is when he clicks in the subject's button, all the users (learners) in the database which are doing that grade and subject -which is clicked- should be displayed

```
<div class="row">
    @if(count(Auth::user()->grades) > 0)
        @foreach(Auth::user()->grades as $grade)
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold">{{$grade->name}}</h5>
                    <hr>
                    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Subjects:</h6>
                    @foreach(Auth::user()->subjects as $subject)
                        <div class="m-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">{{ $subject->name }}</button>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <h3 class="col-md-12 offset-md-5">No Grades to display</h3>   
    @endif
    </div>
```

How do I send the request to the controller and the controller should query the database and bring all the required learners

```
public function showLearners(...)
{ 

    // 

}
```

The User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;

use App\Events\UserRegistered;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    
     /**
     * The event map for the model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];    

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'related' => 'array',
    ];

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        if (is_null($this->last_name)) {
            return "{$this->name}";
        }

        return "{$this->name} {$this->last_name}";
    }

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Grade');
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us with your relationship.

Comment: @Sok Chanty - All relationships have many-to-many (user, grades, subjects)